# how to use the .impl methods in forge viewer V7*

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I have been using following **.impl** methods in V6*

viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.invalidate
viewerApp.getCurrentViewer().impl.matman()._materials

How to proceed with V7*

Thank you

EDIT :

```js
      var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
          var token = accessToken;
          var timeInSeconds = 3600; 
          onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
      };
    
      var documentId = "urn:" + urn;
    
      Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
    
        var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
        viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv);
        var startedCode = viewer.start();
    
        if (startedCode > 0) {
            console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
            return;
        }
    
        console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
        Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
      });
```

...
Then I'm using impl methods as below ..

```js
     var mats = viewer.impl.matman()._materials;
```

But I still get the error

> Cannot read property 'impl' of null

not sure why but may be my global **viewer** variable is null , any idea why this is happening or what have i done wrong.

Comment: It could be a timing issue - perhaps you're trying to access the global viewer variable before it has been initialized. Try putting a breakpoint on the line where you initialize the `viewer` variable and see if it gets called in time.

Answer (score 1):

Anything under the `impl` is typically considered *internal implementation*, and as such should not be relied on in production code. With that said, the `impl` property is still available, and if needed, you can use it in Forge Viewer version 7.* like so:

```js
const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(...);
viewer.impl.invalidate();
viewer.impl.matman();
```

Comment: Thank you  , one more thing  does https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid tutorial only supports viewer V7* ?

Comment: I believe this particular feature should work with v6 as well (the only thing that's required from the viewer API point-of-view is the conversion of world coordinates to on-canvas coordinates, and v6 can definitely do that, too) but there might be some minor adjustments needed.

Comment: Hi @Petr, i get the following error though for V7* ,
"Cannot read property 'impl' of undefined"  what I'm trying is  ,var mats = viewerApp.impl.matman()._materials;'

Comment: I see. When moving from v6 to v7 you do need to change a couple of things (see the [migration guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/change_history/changelog_v7/migration_guide_v6_to_v7/)).  The `impl` object is still there, but instead of accessing it via a "viewer app" (`viewerApp.impl`) you'll need to access it via an instance of "Viewer3D" (`viewer.impl`).

Comment: Hi @Petr ,  I still get the error so I have updated the OP with my code snippet.